# Retrieve data by comparing relational data's last records value

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I have following tables Each customer has multiple followups

[image: Schema image]

[image: Data Image]

and wanted to retrieve **customerslist** where **Followups.attendedDate > customer.attendedDate** and **where [most recent for customer] Followup.statusid=2 or 7 or 8 or 9**

Code I did

```
    Dim Result As List(Of Customer) = Await db.Customers.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.AttendedDate) _
.Include(Function(x) x.FollowUps.Select(Function(y) y.CallStatu)) _
.Where(Function(x) x.AttendedBy IsNot Nothing Andalso 
 x.FollowUps.Any(Function(z) z.StatusID = 2 Or z.StatusID = 7 Or z.StatusID = 8 Or z.StatusID = 9)) _
.Where(Function(x) x.FollowUps.Where(Function(y) y.AttendedDate > x.AttendedDate).Count > 0).ToListAsync
    
    '''To remove status other than 2, 7, 8, 9 add entries to list named removelist                           
        Dim RemoveList As New List(Of Customer)
    
    'Find entries without last status value 2,7,8,9 for each customer
        For Each cust As Customer In Result
            If cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 2 And cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 7 And cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 8 cust.FollowUps.Last.StatusID <> 9 Then
                RemoveList.Add(cust)
            End If
        Next
        
    'Remove entries from original result    
    For Each Cust As Customer In RemoveList
            Result.Remove(Cust)
        Next
```

Query gives customerlist where customers where statusID = 2|7|8|9 matches. But I want customers only with a most recent statusID=2|7|8|9.

So, in given sample data Customer Steve should be in result list as his last status is followup(2). Customer John Should not be in list as it has no followups. Customer Mark also should not be in result list as among his all status his last/latest status is NotInterested(1)

TIA

Comment: Well not an answer, just wanted to make sure you realize the hole your digging.  StatusId I'm assuming is an AutoInc value in your db, your treating it as a consent in your code.  While might work now, there is some real scope that these can get out of sync for various reasons

Comment: Also not an answer, but you might also want to consider at least during the coding phase to break your query up into manageable chucks debugging before jumping straight into the one liner with heaps of conditions.  Eg, get the customers you're interested in, get the Followups you're interested in so you can ensure you've got it right, then put it together

Comment: Did you know in VB that you can write `_` and then put code on the next line? You can even omit it in various places (but I never care to remember the rules, and some of them make for pretty ugly code, so I tend to stick to using underscore for breaking long lines up)

Comment: *I want customers only with a last statusID=2|7|8|9 among his all status.* - what does "last among all" mean? An element is either last or not; it isn't "among" (anywhere within) anything. Do you mean "the most recent status ID, according to date x, is in 2,7,8,9.."

Comment: @CaiusJard, you almost never need the line continuation character. I don't think that I've had to use it once in the last decade or more. If you end a line with a character/keyword that cannot be the end of a valid expression then the compiler will pretty much always assume the expression continues on the next line. Common examples are dots, commas and `Boolean` operators, e.g. `And`.

Comment: That's what I meant by "ugly code".. ending LINQ Where(). on a period and starting the next line with Select just feels wrong to me, despite the rules of English!

Comment: BTW, you should always use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` in preference to `And` and `Or` unless you explicitly want to avoid short-circuiting. Such cases SHOULD be very, VERY rare.

Comment: @CaiusJard, I have to disagree with your characterisation there. If you have a long expression with multiple member accesses, lining up the members vertically and ending each line with a dot makes the code more readable, so hardly ugly. A common example of that would be LINQ queries using function syntax. Another common example would be literal arrays, where putting each element on its own line can also improve readability. Long `Boolean` expressions with multiple conditions on separate lines is also more readable. I couldn't disagree with you more, in fact.

Comment: Yep, that's the good thing about opinions! Good thing about underscores is that they're fairly unobtrusive so if you do want to use them to break a line wherever you like they're not even as in-your-face as C#'s semicolons. All in I think one thing we agree on is that the code in the question would benefit from some liberal use of the enter key..

Comment: Sorry for bad description updated it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to start from FollowUps and work back to Customer. This implicitly removes customers with zero FollowUps..

```
Dim stats = { 2,7,8,9 }

db.FollowUps.Include(Function(fu) fu.Customer) _
  .GroupBy(Function(fu) fu.CustomerId) _
  .Select(Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(fu) fu.AttendedDate).First()) _ 
  .Where(Function(fu) stats.Contains(fu.StatusId) AndAlso fu.AttendedDate > fu.Customer.AttendedDate) _
  .Select(Function(fu) fu.Customer)
```

It might be possible to make the include implicit by moving the where for the attendeddates earlier

```
db.FollowUps _
  .Where(Function(fu) fu.AttendedDate > fu.Customer.AttendedDate) _
  .GroupBy(Function(fu) fu.CustomerId) _
  .Select(Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(fu) fu.AttendedDate).First()) _ 
  .Where(Function(fu) stats.Contains(fu.StatusId)) _
  .Select(Function(fu) fu.Customer)
```

I'm fairly sure that EF can translate this pattern.. but not in a position to test atm.. drop a comment if you get a "query couldn't be translated"

Comment: It is working like a charm. Thanks for help. Only problem is status order in descending but only date wise time comes in ascending order(for same date)

Comment: I didn't quite understand the problem.. Date and time are part of the same field so when you do a "orderbydescending date" it should put e.g. 2000-01-01 18:00 before 2000-01-01 15:00, so you should get the latest(most recent) date first..

Comment: Did you mean that if there are multiple records with exactly same date then you want to use StatusID to split the tie? You can add `.ThenByDescending(Function(fu) fu.StatusID))` betwee the `orderby()` and the `.first`

Comment: updated details in new answer

Comment: It should have been posted as a new question..

Comment: Hi, Caius Jard, Is there any way I can replace .Select(Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(fu) fu.AttendedDate).First()) _ with something like MAX(function(x) x.AttendedDate) as Order by clause is taking so long and has poor performance. TIA

Comment: Is FollowupId an autonumber?

Answer (score 0):

After running EF query

```
db.FollowUps _
  .Where(Function(fu) fu.AttendedDate > fu.Customer.AttendedDate) _
  .GroupBy(Function(fu) fu.CustomerId) _
  .Select(Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(fu) fu.AttendedDate).First()) _ 
  .Where(Function(fu) stats.Contains(fu.StatusId)) _
  .Select(Function(fu) fu.Customer)
```

when I Run below code to check retrieved values

```
For Each cust As Customer In result2
    Debug.WriteLine(cust.Firstname & " " & cust.Lastname)
    For Each fw As FollowUp In cust.FollowUps
        Debug.WriteLine(fw.CallStatu.Status & vbTab & fw.AttendedDate)
    Next
Debug.WriteLine("---------------------")
Next
```

### as a result I get

Chirag Panchal
**Document Pickup   17/09/2021 12:02:03 PM 

Document Pickup 17/09/2021 12:02:20 PM

Document Pickup 17/09/2021 12:04:33 PM

Document Pickup 17/09/2021 12:06:48 PM

Documents Received  17/09/2021 12:26:33 PM**

Follow up   13/09/2021 5:06:28 PM
Interested  13/09/2021 5:07:02 PM
Interested  01/09/2021 11:56:38 AM
"---------------------"
Ravibhai Prajapati
Document Pickup 01/09/2021 11:56:45 AM

where dates seems to be in descending order but respective time is in ascending order for each record

Comment: But, there isn't any certain order specified for FollowUps so they're just coming in whatever order the database feels like sending them. Put an OrderBy? example `For Each fw As FollowUp In cust.FollowUps.OrderBy(Function(fu) fu.AttendedDate)`

Comment: did it Thank you very much.